# Javascript hide values depending on a selected option

Tags: javascript, php, html, twig

I need help with some javascript. The idea is to hide some values from a  depending on a parent

here is the html

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phase</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" name="phase" id="phase">
            {%if phases is defined%}
                {%for phase in phases%}
                    <option  value="{{phase.id}}">{{phase.nom}}</option>
                {%endfor%}
            {%endif%}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" >
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sous phase</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" name="ssphase" id="ssphase">
            {%if ssphases is defined%}
                {%for ssphase in ssphases%}
                    <option  value="{{ssphase.id}}" id="{{ssphase.phaseid}}">{{ssphase.nom}}</option>
                {%endfor%}
            {%endif%}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do you have any idea to make the javascript hide options with the id that doesnt match with the value of the option selected on the first select?

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Hiding an option in a select is not a good idea as there will be browser-compatibility-problems. Best way is to remove/add the options dynamically using javascript. There are multiple ways to achieve this: E.g. keep a list of all select-options and output the ones that match your criteria using JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
phase.onchange = function () {
    show_sphases (this.value);
}

function show_sphases (phase) {
    var subphases = document.querySelectorAll("[data-phase='" + phase + "']");
    var allSubphases = document.querySelectorAll("#ssphase option");

    for (var i = 0; i <= allSubphases.length; i++ ){
        var item = allSubphases.item(i);
        $(item).hide();
    }

    for (var i = 0; i <= subphases.length; i++ ){
        var item = subphases.item(i);
        $(item).show();
    }
}
```

You also have to add a data-phase attribute to your ssphases options so that you can link them together, like this:

```
<option  value="11" id="11" data-phase="1">Subphase #1-1</option>
```

I used jQuery for `$().hide` and `$().show`.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bq5dgn4/3).

Comment: does exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you.